# How often an approximate location should be updated on Android 12

Tags: android, geolocation

I have an App trying to test on Android 12. The App needs the location service. By default, the FINE and COARSE location permissions are requested. What I find is that if I enabled the approximate location, the initial location is updated then the approximate location is not updated as expected within the time and distance thresholds. Any suggestions? Is this expected behavior on Android 12? Thanks

Comment: Post your actual code so we can see what calls you're using and answer better.  Are you using an emulator or real device?  Is your location actually changing, or are you just expecting an update with the same info?  Are you using LocationManager or FusedProvider?

Comment: Please note that if you're using LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates, those are the MINIMUM amount of time and distance between updates.  Not a refresh rate.  So if you use 1000 ms, it doesn't assure an update every second, it assures you won't get it more frequently than that.

Comment: @GabeSechan we are using LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates with NETWORK and GPS providers to update the location, if the App proximate location is enabled, once it is updated,  after that, the location is not updated anymore.  How is the proximate location calculated or what factors are affecting its updating?

Comment: If you don't have FINE permission, GPS won't work at all or will be majorly fuzzed.  As for what factors effect updating-  the system needs to think you have significantly moved.  The distance needed will be larger for NETWORK than GPS.  To get a new value, you'd need to see significant change in either wifi or cellular network signal strength.  Your best way to test is to use a mock provider and control when the location changes for testing.

Comment: IT makes very much sense, thanks!